# Add alert to tradingview plotshape

Tags: tradingview-api

I have this code  and i want to add an alert condition every time the plotshape signal is show.

```
    //@version=4
study("Bollinger Band Bounce", overlay=true)

//Bollinger Band
source = close
length = input(15, minval=1), mult = input(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50)
basis = sma(source, length)
dev = mult * stdev(source, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
//plot(basis, color=#FF0000)
p1 = plot(upper, color=#0000FF)
p2 = plot(lower, color=#0000FF)
fill(p1, p2)

BBB=iff(((open-lower)/(upper-lower)*100)<30 and (close>close[1]),open,0)

plotshape(BBB,color=#0000ff ,style=shape.labeldown)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Is this the code you want?

Because the alert will show once per bar, so if you are on the timeframe 4H, you should do this:

```
BBB4H =  security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", BBB, barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

and then go to 1 minute chart to set the alert

```
if (BBB4H)
    alert("Alert", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```